# How to add metadata to a tensorflow lite file converted from a tensorflow file

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to add a tensorflow lite file to Android studio but when I add it, I get an error saying metadata not found. I have the tensorflow model working remotely on my laptop to a 70% accuracy. I used the following code to convert from tensorflow to tensorflow lite.

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1]),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=16, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error') # compile the model
model.fit(x=[-1, 0, 1], y=[-3, -1, 1], epochs=5) # train the model

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()


with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

Error message on Android Studio – “No metadata found”
It gives the following link to add metadata https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata I couldn’t get the script given to work

Can anyone explain to me how I would adapt this script to fit my model please or any alternative solution? I have spent weeks searching for a solution I haven't found anything, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Metadata is required when there is a need to use tflite support library.  Since you already have the converted tflite model, you can use tflite interpreter API directly to run the converted model. Please refer to the tflite android page. https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android

Comment: Hi Jae, thank you for your response. I just looked at the link you provided and I have added the tflite file as shown in the link and I get the error saying no metadata. I should have mentioned the tensorflow model is trained in python so I am not sure how I would call the API? I can only see an example for C code, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The message "No metadata is shown" is not an error. It just says it does not have the metadata. You can ignore it when you are not depending on the TFLite support library. There is a Java API for android: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_java

Comment: Hi Jae, thanks for the response. I'm not sure if I require the TFLite support library? I am implementing a dog breed recognition feature which takes an image from the users camera roll and adds it to firebase, then the app would run the tflite file on this image giving a result. This is my first time using neural networks so I would appreciate any advice you can give on how to get it implemented. Thanks

Comment: Please refer to the following links: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/recognize-flowers-with-tensorflow-on-android/index.html#0

Comment: Hi Jae, thank you for the suggestions. I have already trained and tested my TensorFlow model to a 70% accuracy locally on my laptop so the first link didn't provide any further guidance. In the second link, I am finding it difficult to adapt it to my own model. I am not using the camera at all, the user upload from their gallery, also it has a lot of blank methods which I don't know how to implement. Can you explain how I can figure out if my model needs metadata or not please? I'm not sure what the TFLite support library is used for

Comment: TFLite support library helps you create a new model and deploy them with its own easy version API. TFLite support library depends on the metadata for API. However, you already create your own model already in TF. In such cass, you dont need the metadata instead. You can just rely on the TFLite interpreter API. I already mentioned in the above comment.